# gcc: /usr/lib/libxml2.a: No such file or directory

Tags: rhel6, gcc, library

I have installed the following pre-built rpm on RHEL6 32bit:

```
libxml2-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686,
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686,
libxml2-python-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686
```

How can I resolve this issue?

```
gcc: /usr/lib/libxml2.a: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you give a bit of context to your question? On the face of it, there is quite a strong chance this would be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it isn't really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The package you want is `libxml2-static`. It's in the RHEL 6 "Optional" repo.

Comment: Got it now we will see if out error goes away.